# Execute immediate error in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I want to execute the following command through a cursor where I have column name and column values in a different table.

However the script fails with following error message.

ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

```
execute immediate 'UPDATE EMP_DETAILS_T SET ' || EMP_REC.COLUMN_NAME || ' = ' || '''' || EMP_REC.VALUE ||''' ' || ' where employee_id = ' || ''''|| EMP_REC.EMPLOYEE_ID || ''' '  ;
```

entire command is as follow.

```
DECLARE 
CURSOR CR_EMP_ATT IS
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,
       VALUE,
       EMPLOYEE_ID
FROM  UPDATE_DATA_T
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = P_EMP_ID;

BEGIN


FOR CR_EMP IN CR_EMP_ATT LOOP

    BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Update EMP_DETAILS_T set ' || CR_EMP.COLUMN_NAME || ' = ' ||''''||CR_EMP.VALUE||''''|| '  where employee_id  =  ' ||''''|| P_EMP_ID||'''';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('temp table updated');
    END;

END LOOP;

END;
```

I have placed this query in a procedure to run when needed by employee.

Comment: can't debug your statement, but here some ideas: 1. try adding a semicolon to your statement - 2. try removing the quotes sorrounding the employee_id (i assume it is an integer, not a varchar) 3. if this doesnt work, try saving the statement string to a constant and use placeholders and the "using"-Syntax for execute immediate (keyword: bind variables)

Comment: Don't add a semicolon for an execute immediate call, that's not valid, and the quotes won't cause this error even if your ID is a number. Do use bind variables for the employee ID and value. Can you add a `dbms_output` call before the `execute immediate` to show the command that's actually going to be executed, to see which values it fails on? Are any of your `column_name` values reserved words, perhaps?

Comment: @Alex Poole : when removed semicolon it gives error.

Comment: Or do any of your value or ID values have a single quote in them - maybe if you have a column with names in you have an O'Brien or something? That would cause this error; and would be revealed by displaying the statement being executed. And would be fixed by using bind variables...

Comment: @user3494938 - I didn't mean to remove the semicolon you have after the call now; I was disagreeing with the advice to *add* a semicolon inside the dynamic statement.

Comment: I hope the error is the value contain ampersand marks. Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `value` column includes values which contain a single quote. (The ampersand isn't going to be a problem here). You can see how that breaks the statement by displaying it before execution:

```
dbms_output.put_line('Update EMP_DETAILS_T set ' || CR_EMP.COLUMN_NAME
  || ' = ' ||''''||CR_EMP.VALUE||''''|| '  where employee_id  =  '
  ||''''|| P_EMP_ID||'''');
```

... which reveals:

```
Update EMP_DETAILS_T set SOME_COLUMN = 'Standard & Poor's'  where employee_id  =  'ABC123'
```

... which has unbalanced single quotes; you can even see that in the syntax highlighting.

The simplest fix is to use bind variables for the two values - you can't for the column name - and pass the actual values with the `USING` clause:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Update EMP_DETAILS_T set ' || CR_EMP.COLUMN_NAME
    || ' = :VALUE where employee_id = :EMP_ID'
    USING CR_EMP.VALUE, P_EMP_ID;
```

Answer (score 2):

Does your value CR_EMP.VALUE contain any `'` character?

That would be another reason to use bind variables, i.e.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Update EMP_DETAILS_T set '||CR_EMP.COLUMN_NAME||' = ' :val WHERE employee_id = :id' 
USING CR_EMP.VALUE, P_EMP_ID;
```